# MPI_Recv() freezing program, not receiving value from MPI_Send() in C

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to write an implementation of a hyper quicksort in MPI, but I'm having an issue where a process gets stuck on `MPI_Recv()`.

While testing with 2 processes, it seems that inside the `else` of the `if (rank % comm_sz == 0)`, process 1 is never receiving the pivot from process 0. Process 0 successfully sends its pivot and recurses through the method correctly. If put in some print debug statements and received the output:

```
(arr, 0, 2, 0, 9)
Rank 0 sending pivot 7 to 1
(arr, 1, 2, 0, 9)
Rank 1 pre-recv from 0
```

After which, the post-recv message from rank 1 never prints. Rank 0 prints its post-send message and continues through its section of the array. Is there something wrong with my implementation of `MPI_Send()` or `MPI_Recv()` that may be causing this?

Here is my code for the quicksort:

(For reference, `comm_sz` in the parameters for the method refers to the number of processes looking at that section of the array.)

```
void hyper_quick(int *array, int rank, int comm_sz, int s, int e) {
    printf("(arr, %d, %d, %d, %d)\n", rank, comm_sz, s, e);
    // Keeps recursing until there is only one element
    if (s < e) {
            int pivot;
            if (comm_sz > 1) {
                    // One process gets a random pivot within its range and sends that to every process looking at that range
                    if (rank % comm_sz == 0) {
                            pivot = rand() % (e - s) + s;
                            for (int i = rank + 1; i < comm_sz; i++) {
                                    int partner = rank + i;
                                    printf("Rank %d sending pivot %d to %d\n", rank, pivot, partner);
                                    MPI_Send(&pivot, 1, MPI_INT, partner, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                                    printf("Rank %d successfully sent %d to %d\n", rank, pivot, partner);
                            }
                    }
                    else {
                            int partner = rank - (rank % comm_sz);
                            printf("Rank %d pre-recv from %d\n", rank, partner);
                            MPI_Recv(&pivot, 1, MPI_INT, partner, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                            printf("Rank %d received pivot %d from %d\n", rank, pivot, partner);
                    }
            }
            else {
                    pivot = rand() % (e - s) + s;
            }
            int tmp = array[pivot];
            array[pivot] = array[e];
            array[e] = tmp;
            // Here is where the actual quick sort happens
            int i = s;
            int j = e - 1;
            while (i < j) {
                    while (array[e] >= array[i] && i < j) {
                            i++;
                    }
                    while (array[e] < array[j] && i < j) {
                            j--;
                    }
                    if (i < j) {
                            tmp = array[i];
                            array[i] = array[j];
                            array[j] = tmp;
                    }
            }
            if (array[e] < array[i]) {
                    tmp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[e];
                    array[e] = tmp;
                    pivot = i;
            }
            else {
                    pivot = e;
            }
            // Split remaining elements between remaining processes
            if (comm_sz > 1) {
                    // Elements greater than pivot
                    if (rank % comm_sz >= comm_sz/2) {
                            hyper_quick(array, rank, comm_sz/2, pivot + 1, e);
                    }
                    // Elements lesser than pivot
                    else {
                            hyper_quick(array, rank, comm_sz/2, s, pivot - 1);
                    }
            }
            // Recurse remaining elements in current process
            else {
                    hyper_quick(array, rank, 1, s, pivot - 1);
                    hyper_quick(array, rank, 1, pivot + 1, e);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Rank 0 sending pivot 7 to 1
MPI_Send(&pivot, 1, MPI_INT, partner, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                                      ^^^^
```

So the sender tag is zero.

```
Rank 1 pre-recv from 0
MPI_Recv(&pivot, 1, MPI_INT, partner, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                                      ^^^^
```

And the receiver tag is one.

If the receiver asks for only messages with a specific tag, it will not receive a message with a different tag.

> Sometimes there are cases when A might have to send many different types of messages to B. Instead of B having to go through extra measures to differentiate all these messages, MPI allows senders and receivers to also specify message IDs with the message (known as tags). When process B only requests a message with a certain tag number, messages with different tags will be buffered by the network until B is ready for them. [[MPI Tutorial -- Send and Receive](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-send-and-receive/)]

Comment: Doi, I can't believe I've been looking at these two lines of code and didn't notice I made the tags different. Thank you so much for your help!